# Setting up pub/sub subscription across different project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In my GCP project (project **A**) I have created a Pub/sub topic (**topicA**) and messages published in this pub/sub topic needs to be consumed in other GCP project (project **B**) by Subscription (**subscriptionB**).

What's the recommended way of setting up **subscriptionB** ?

1. Define **subscriptionB** in project A and add service account from project B with appropriate IAM permission.
2. Define **subscriptionB** in project B. In cloud console it's possible to attach subscription from different topic by granting pubsub.topic.attachSubscription (shown below).

Is approach 2 even possible ? If yes, then when to use approach 2 and what all needs to be done for approach 2 ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 2 approach are possible, and there is also a 3rd one.

1. use the role `roles/pubsub.subscriber` on the service account of the projectB, on the subscription (or the project) of the project A
2. You need to have the role `roles/pubsub.subscriber` on the topic that you want (or the project) on the project A. As defined in the message, you need, at least the permission `pubsub.topics.attachSubscription` on the topic (or the project). For this, you can create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) if you want to grant only this permission and [not the 2 others of the role `roles/pubsub.subscriber`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#roles)
3. The third solution is based on the solution 1, create a subscription in the project A, but a Push subscription, and push the messages to a HTTP endpoint. No authentication required in the Project B this time. However, if you want to protect your HTTP endpoint (for example deployed on Cloud Run or Cloud Functions), you will need, [in the push subscription in the projectA, to have the correct authorization to call the endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#authentication_and_authorization_by_the_push_endpoint) in projectB

Answer (score 0):

- A Google Cloud Function can't be triggered by a subsription to a topic of another project (since you can't subscribe to another project's topic).
- But a Google Cloud Function can **publish** to a topic of another project (and then subscribers of this topic will be triggered).

I solved it by establishing a Google Cloud Function in the original project which listens to the original topic and reacts with publishing to a new topic in the other project. Therefore, the service account (*...@appspot.gserviceaccount.com*) of this function "in the middle" needs to be authorized by the new topic (*console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic/detail/...?project=...*), i.e. add principal with role: "*Pub/Sub Publisher*"

[image]

```
import base64
import json
import os

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1


#https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub?hl=en#publishing_a_message_from_within_a_function


# Instantiates a Pub/Sub client
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

def notify(event, context):
    project_id = os.environ.get('project_id')  
    topic_name = os.environ.get('topic_name')  

    # References an existing topic
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)  

    message_json = json.dumps({
        'data': {'message': 'here would be the message'},  # or you can pass the message of event/context
    })
    message_bytes = message_json.encode('utf-8')

    # Publishes a message
    try:
        publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message_bytes)
        publish_future.result()  # Verify the publish succeeded
        return 'Message published.'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return (e, 500)
```