# Trigger Google Cloud function in one project on publish in Google PubSub from another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

There is an application already pushing to Google PubSub topic `T1` in a different project and I would like to have the Google Cloud function triggered by the publishing on `T1`. I read the official document https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub that it is not possible to trigger cross-project and tried creating the cloud function too from the GCP console but do not see the topics from other projects even though I have access to those projects

I am looking for alternatives. Is it possible to achieve it in a different way?

Comment: Have a look at this, with usage of Cloud Run and PubSub: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/cross-region-and-cross-project-event-routing-eventarc-and-pubsub Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use HTTP communication and not native event communication. I mean you have to change your Background functions (that you plug on a PubSub topic) in a HTTP function.

By doing that, you also have to create a PubSub push subscription on your PubSub topic and to add the Cloud Functions HTTP URL as target.

Don't forget to configure the security part to allow only secure and authenticated communication between PubSub and your Function.

---

Alternatively, you can follow Piotr advice (in comment) and use other HTTP oriented product, like Cloud RUn. But the principle is still the same: PubSub push subscription is the key!

Comment: I created a Google pubsub topic and its `push` subscription in Project A with the Trigger URL set to the Cloud function URL which is created in Project B. Also, I assigned the role `roles/cloudfunctions.invoker` to the service account in project A, but still, the cloud function is not called on Publish. I must be missing something.

Comment: This answered the above thing - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62373846#comment13

Comment: You have to grant the service account that you put on your Push subscription on the Project B! Or better, on the Cloud Functions itself

Comment: Is there a way to handle this without a HTTP push notification (with native event comm?) I read the first option in the response on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496797/setting-up-pub-sub-subscription-across-different-project but I havent tried myself, would that option work for native event comm?

Comment: What's native event comm? Pull subscription?

Comment: Exactly! (native event communication as you metion in your response)

Comment: I read the issue tracker and realize that the only expected way for this is with push messages for now, so we have to wait until the cross project pull is available